# 2 Spring @JmsListeners on 1 queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I have 2 `@JmsListener` instances on 1 queue, and I want to take a fixed number of messages from the queue and then hold the rest in pending for some time for bulk processing. I have added the condition to check the number of pending message, but due to 2 listeners it is failing. Also, I have to add this condition only inside `@JmsListener`.

Please suggest how to add the logic of taking fixed messages from queue and holding the rest in pending for achieving throttling.

Comment: When you say, "...holding the rest in pending..." do you mean hold the messages on the _consumer_ or on the _broker_?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you will be able to use Spring's `@JmsListener` to do what you want because you simply don't have the control of the consumer which you need to fetch multiple messages and then process them all at once. A listener only gets one message at time and it is invoked as messages arrive so you have no control over when and how you fetch the messages in contrast to a normal [JMS `MessageConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html) which you can use to manually invoke `receive()` as many times as you like.

Also, ActiveMQ will do its best to treat each consumer fairly and therefore distribute the same amount of messages to each. Generally speaking, it is *bad* for one consumer to get all (or most) the messages as it can starve the other consumers and waste resources. That said, you could potentially use [consumer priority](https://activemq.apache.org/consumer-priority) if you really needed some consumers to get more messages than others.